# Grouping of TestCaseSource in Allure Report

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, allure

I am currently new to Selenium automation testing using NUnit and Allure for reporting.

I have managed to do up some simple web automation testing scenarios and able to display the results on Allure just fine.

Moving on to a bit more advanced scenarios, I am looking at recursively executing a [Test] based on multiple datasets (in CSV/Excel). I have read that this is achievable via [TestCaseSource].

My first attempt was running the .csproject via command line dotnet test --logger:trx to generate the report. For this attempt, all [TestCaseSource] was triggered, but only the first one was tagged to the TestClass.

[Test] which is in easyFormDemo.cs:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(ModelTestCaseSource), "GetTestCaseDaysCSV", new object[] { "../netcoreapp3.1/data.csv" })]
public void formDemo3(DataDays dataDays)
{
    driver.Url = "https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html";

    string sendkey = dataDays.Day;
    IWebElement msg = driver.FindElement(By.Id("user-message"));
    msg.SendKeys(sendkey);

    IWebElement btn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='Show Message']"));
            btn.Click();

    string display = driver.FindElement(By.Id("display")).Text;

    Assert.AreEqual(sendkey, display);
}
```

ModelTestCaseSource.cs:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTestCaseDaysCSV(string path)
{
    DataTable dt = CSVReader.ConvertCSVtoDataTable(path);
    
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var dataDays = new DataDays();
        dataDays.Day = row["Day"].ToString();
        yield return new TestCaseData(new object[] { dataDays });
    }
}
```

(Unable to directly upload an image sorry)

Allure Report Image running test via command line:
[Allure Report Image via command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khXU3.png)

As seen from the image, only the first TestCaseSource of formDemo3 was attached to TestSelenium.easyFormDemo.
The rest of the TestCaseSource of formDemo3 was appended to the bottom separately.

I then looked around more and read about NUnit.Allure nuget package.
I imported the nuget and configured the [AllureParentSuite] and [AllureSuite] accordingly.

[Test] which is in easyFormDemo.cs:

```
[AllureParentSuite("FormDemo")]
.
.
.
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(ModelTestCaseSource), "GetTestCaseDaysCSV", new object[] { "../netcoreapp3.1/data.csv" })]
[AllureSuite("FormDemo3")]
public void formDemo3(DataDays dataDays)
{
    driver.Url = "https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html";

    string sendkey = dataDays.Day;
    IWebElement msg = driver.FindElement(By.Id("user-message"));
    msg.SendKeys(sendkey);

    IWebElement btn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='Show Message']"));
            btn.Click();

    string display = driver.FindElement(By.Id("display")).Text;

    Assert.AreEqual(sendkey, display);
}
```

I then triggered the project via Visual Studio Test Viewer. The issue now is that although all the TestCaseSource was triggered, only the first TestCaseSource gets captured in the Allure Report.

Allure Report Image running with AllureSuite:
[Allure Report Image via AllureSuite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj8ot.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am unable to find any links/help on this currently.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be generating IEnumerable from your TestCaseSource.

When using TestCaseSource it is important to generate a unique test name for reporting to work. More importantly, a good report name will make your report look amazing.

**TestCaseSource usage**

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCaseSource() =>         
    MyTestCaseSourceFunction();

[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCaseSource))]
public void CanDiscoverEndPoints(string param1)
```

**Constructing a TestCaseData**

```
Return an IEnumerable<TestCaseData> for your purpose.

new TestCaseData("parameter value")
{
    TestName = $"MyTestName-{apiRoot}{api}{op.Operation.Method}"
}
```